# Azure AD B2B and B2C in same Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

I have requirement to create a web application using AzureAD, where user may login from Organization/using their personal account(FB,Google, etc..) Can we use both B2B and B2C in same Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Azure AD B2B Collaboration is a feature that is not available for Azure AD B2C tenants**.

However, the **ability to add Azure AD as an IdP in B2C should be available very soon**. Vote for it in the Azure AD B2C UserVoice forum to support this ask and be informed on updates on it's progress: [Add an Azure AD Identity Provider](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/9865695-add-an-azure-ad-identity-provider)

Alternatively, you do this in your app by setting it up to support multiple identity providers (Azure AD B2C and Azure AD). See junaas post: [how to federate between Azure B2B and B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552128/how-to-federate-between-azure-b2b-and-b2c)